# Fullcalendar unclear how to import the date and description from a event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, fullcalendar-5

I'm building a webpage where people list in their movie streams through Google Calendar which than displays on the webpage via Fullcalendar. The title of the event comes through but the timeslot and the description are not. Does anyone know how to?

This is my code so far: (I removed the API Key and Client ID in this example)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link href='lib/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='lib/main.js'></script>
    <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.13.1/css/all.css' rel='stylesheet'>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
      
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
          initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
          googleCalendarApiKey: 'XXX',
          events: {
            googleCalendarId: 'XXX@group.calendar.google.com'
          }        
        });
      
        calendar.render();
      });
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Screenshot of the event in Fullcalendar:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is controlled by some code within fullCalendar. So you either modify the source code or you write your own code to download this data, then you can control what it fetches. You'd then have to write code to display the description, as fullCalendar doesn't display custom fields by default.

Comment: P.s. if my answer to your previous question was helpful please remember to mark it as accepted and upvote. If it wasn't helpful, leave a comment to explain. Thanks.

Comment: Could you perhaps help me with the code i have to implement? I tried different approaches already while following the docs on Fullcalendar.io but none have helped so far.

Comment: Based on that I feel like you didn't understand my comments entirely